# Golang Coding Conventions: When to Break Lines in Code?

Tags: go, coding-style, conventions

One of my favorite things about go is `gofmt`. I like the fact that the coding style is standardized in many ways.

However there is one thing that bothers me still: line breaks. I found that if I look at my company's codebase, there is no evident consistency on the question of when to break lines.

Looking at some of the code in the `stdlib`, for example, the `fmt` code [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/fmt/format.go), I'm still not sure what's the convention (if it exists at all).

For example, on `fmt_integer` function [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/fmt/format.go#L194), there are line breaks after `if` statement bodies, but on `fmt_sbx` [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/fmt/format.go#L332) there aren't.

Is there a convention for line breaks in golang? what's considered best practice?

Comment: BTW, you can automate line breaks with: https://github.com/segmentio/golines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there will be at most one empty line after an `if` block (because of `go fmt`).

Second, adding or not an extra blank line does not follow any hard rule, except code readability.

It is not even mentioned in the "[Go Code Review Comments](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments)" wiki page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So basically what you are saying is that there is no standard convention (wasn't asking about a hard rule) for this? Whatever is readable (a somewhat subjective concept) works. I wonder if Google or some other go-intensive organization has something written about this.

Comment: @orcaman "Whatever is readable (a somewhat subjective concept) works": yes, knowing that the only two possibilities here are: no line break after an `if` block, OR one *one* line break (no more than one, so there is an hard rule there).

Comment: thing is, you could easily end up with code that has one line break between each line, which looks annoying, but readable. It can sometimes be hard to tell when it is too much. I for one recently went to write without line breaks whatsoever and I feel that the code is quite readable.